# Error importing modules in thumbor

Tags: python, thumbor

I have installed thumbor using pip on windows when I try to run the thumbor server I get an error like:

```
2016-09-05 11:45:10 thumbor:WARNING Module thumbor.filters.brightness could not
be imported.
2016-09-05 11:45:10 thumbor:WARNING Module thumbor.filters.colorize could not be
 imported.
2016-09-05 11:45:10 thumbor:WARNING Module thumbor.filters.contrast could not be
 imported.
2016-09-05 11:45:10 thumbor:WARNING Module thumbor.filters.rgb could not be impo
rted.
2016-09-05 11:45:10 thumbor:WARNING Module thumbor.filters.round_corner could no
t be imported.
2016-09-05 11:45:10 thumbor:WARNING Module thumbor.filters.noise could not be im
ported.
2016-09-05 11:45:10 thumbor:WARNING Module thumbor.filters.watermark could not b
e imported.
2016-09-05 11:45:10 thumbor:WARNING Module thumbor.filters.equalize could not be
 imported.
2016-09-05 11:45:10 thumbor:WARNING Module thumbor.filters.fill could not be imp
orted.
2016-09-05 11:45:10 thumbor:WARNING Module thumbor.filters.sharpen could not be
imported.
2016-09-05 11:45:10 thumbor:WARNING Module thumbor.filters.frame could not be im
ported.
2016-09-05 11:45:10 thumbor:WARNING Module thumbor.filters.convolution could not
 be imported.
2016-09-05 11:45:10 thumbor:WARNING Module thumbor.filters.blur could not be imp
orted.
2016-09-05 11:45:10 thumbor:WARNING Module thumbor.filters.saturation could not
be imported.
2016-09-05 11:45:10 thumbor:WARNING Module thumbor.filters.curve could not be im
ported.
2016-09-05 11:45:10 thumbor:WARNING Error importing bounding_box filter, trimmin
g won't work
```

I need immediate help on the matter. 
I will be exteremely thankful for the solutions

Answer (score 0):

Seems this issue has already been reported on github [issue-256](https://github.com/thumbor/thumbor/issues/256). Try referring to that.

Comment: I am using windows n these solutions are for ubuntu. I went through these already. Still no luck